# piping a script to ssh, unable to set variable

Tags: linux, bash

I expected it to print `v=1`.  Why does this print `v=`?

```
cat<<DONE|ssh user@host
v=1
echo v=$v
DONE
```

On `host`, bash is the shell.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314660/passing-variables-in-remote-ssh-command

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is equivalent to:

```
echo "v=1;echo v=$v"|ssh user@host
```

What you want is:

```
echo 'v=1;echo v=$v'|ssh user@host
```

You can achieve this by using `cat<<'DONE'` instead of `cat<<DONE`.

Answer (score 4):

Variables are expanded inside heredocs. You need to escape the `$` with a `\`