# SSHpass : to access local variable on remote host

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ssh, sshpass

Unable to access local variable on remote host using sshpass. Can you please help me to pass local variable to pass on remote host using ssh pass for the below code snippet

```
name="Stack over flow"  
sshpass -p${serverpassword} ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ${username}@${servername} 'for i in $name ; do echo $i ; done'
```

expected result:

```
stack
over
flow
```

Comment: can someone please suggest

Comment: [Passing variables in remote ssh command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3314660/608639), [How do I pass a variable from my local server to a remote server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23996742/608639), [How do I pass a variable from my local server to a remote server?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/134114), [How to use sshpass?](https://askubuntu.com/q/282319), etc. More generally, [this search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22SSHpass%22+access+local+variable+on+remote+host+site:stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
name="Stack over flow"  
sshpass -p${serverpassword} ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ${username}@${servername} \
"for i in \\$name; do echo \$i; done"
```

You need to double quote your command line and right [escaping](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Escape-Character).