# How to execute a command over ssh and store the value in a variable

Tags: linux, shell, ssh

I am trying to  get the value of uname -r from a remote machine over ssh and use that value in my local script flow.

```
kern_ver=uname -r
sshpass -p "$passwd" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$c 'kern_ver=echo \$kern_ver'
```

But looks like the value is not getting passed back to the local script flow .

Comment: [Passing variables in remote ssh command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3314660/608639), [How do I pass a variable from my local server to a remote server?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/134114), [How to use sshpass?](https://askubuntu.com/q/282319), etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Storing the command in the variable `cmd` is optional; you can hard-code the command as a string argument to `ssh`. The key is that you simply run the command on the remote host via `ssh`, and capture its output on the local host.

```
cmd="uname -r"
kern_ver=$(sshpass -p "$passwd" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@"$c" "$cmd")
```

Comment: "hard-code" is an important point: If the command *isn't* entirely hardcoded but includes parameterized portions, more complex techniques  are required to prevent shell injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

Capture is `var=$(...)`, as always.

ssh is a bit interesting because it unconditionally invokes a remote shell, so working with completely arbitrary commands (as opposed to simple things like `uname -r`) requires a different technique:

```
filename="/path/to/name with spaces/and/ * wildcard characters *"
printf -v cmd_str '%q ' ls -l "$filename"
output=$(ssh "$host" "$cmd_str")
```

This way you can use arguments with spaces, and they'll be passed with correct quoting through to the remote system (with the caveat that non-printable characters may be quoted with bash-only syntax, so this is only guaranteed to work in cases where the remote shell is also bash).