# Accessing export variable on remote server

Tags: linux, ssh

Below is not working when I am trying to access exported variable on remote server under if loop:

```
VAR=`grep pattern ./checklist | cut -f7`
echo "Port number to be checked for service is $VAR" #working fine
export VAR
ssh -tTq user@node <<EOF
echo "checking service on \`hostname\`";
echo "export value received is $VAR"
echo \$(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep port=$VAR | wc -l)
if [ \$(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep port=$VAR | wc -l) == 0 ];
then
echo "service is DOWN"
elif [ \$(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep port=\$VAR | wc -l) == 1 ];
then
echo "Service is Up"
else
echo "Multiple instances running of selected service"
fi
EOF
```

Output received of if loop is not as expected:

Multiple instances running of selected service
+ '[' 1 == 2 ']'

instead of 1 == 1 condition match

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing variables in remote ssh command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314660/passing-variables-in-remote-ssh-command)

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer by myself.
In the above question I have missed \  before $VAR by mistake in elif condition.

LL: Strong/single quotes ' should be avoided for the cmds to be executed on remote host when using export variables via ssh.

Avoid using \ on under while calling export variable present between << EOF ..... EOF. (In above example $VAR)