# Running local script over ssh with user input

Tags: bash

How does user input work for running local scripts remotely?

My script uses `$1` for user input.

The remote machine names vary, so I wrote a script(`main_script.sh`), which also uses `$1` to read the name of the remote machine.

Ex:

```
./main_script.sh remote3 lcl_script.sh <user_in>
```

But user input is not recognized.
`remote3` is the name of the remote machine

Main script:

```
ssh root@$1 'bash -s' < $2
```

where, $1 is for machine name.
$2 is for the local script.

Local script:

```
printf "new setting:"
echo $1
```

where $1 is the user_in

Comment: Please post your scripts.

Answer (score 0):

wrap the script name and user_in in quotes

```
./main_script.sh remote3 "~/lcl_script.sh <user_in>"
```

This question is source of answer

[Passing variables in remote ssh command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314660/passing-variables-in-remote-ssh-command)

Comment: I tried putting in quote, but still didn't work.

Comment: Qualify the full path of the remote script? - eg. :   ./main_script.sh remote3 "~/lcl_script.sh <user_in>"

Comment: Presumably the ssh keys and known_hosts are configured and logging into remote server occurs successfully without needing to enter the password?

Comment: Correct, no need to enter password.

Comment: Are you able to elaborate on what you define as _"But user input is not recognized"_ - what does stdout display (and maybe stderr)?

Comment: whatever I entered in  <user_in>, I wasn't able to see it when I echo'd it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
To make sure the user input is read, I had to add $3 (for user input) in the main script, 
Main script is:

```
ssh root@$1 'bash -s' < $2 $3
```

I didn't have to change anything in the local script. 
@irnerd, thanks for helping out.