# find timestamp in remote server (ssh) specific pattern filename

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ssh

I need to create a script that should get the newest file based on a filename pattern from server A on server B.

The command I run on server B is like this (server A is 103.11.34.111):

```
ssh user@103.11.34.111 'find /data/path -name "CDR*$file_date" -printf "%TY-%Tm-%Td %TH:%TM:%.2TS\n" | sort -rn | head -1'
```

`$file_date` is a variable that defines a date with format YYYYMMDD

I get error as below when I run `./myscript.sh`

```
*** buffer overflow detected ***: ssh terminated
```

I suspect there is issue in my command because if I run the command with

```
ssh user@103.11.34.111 'find /data/path -name "CDR*$file_date" | sort -rn | head -1'
```

or

```
ssh user@103.11.34.111 'find /data/path -printf "%TY-%Tm-%Td %TH:%TM:%.2TS\n" | sort -rn | head -1'
```

it manages to get the result, however if I run with full parameters there is the buffer overflow.

Comment: Why are you using a command substitution here? Do you really genuinely expect the output from `find` to be a command that the remote shell should execute? More to the point, code which doesn't do what you want is a poor way to explain what it is that you do want.

Comment: It seems unlikely that `$file_date` will be set in the remote shell so it is probably processing a lot more files than you had hoped. But all of this is too unclear to provide anything more than random observations in comments.

Comment: file date is date with format YYYYMMDD. its configurable to get yesterday or last 2 days. for command substitution, means that we can remove $( ) ?

Comment: Guessing somewhat wildly, I'd imagine you want something like `ssh user@103.11.34.111 "find /data/path -name 'CDR*$file_date' -printf '%TY-%Tm-%Td %TH:%TM:%.2TS\n' | sort -rn | head -1"` but I have no idea whether that will fix the overflow error. Probably the `sort | head` pipe could be avoided with a simple Awk script which doesn't need to keep more than a single line in memory. `awk '$0 > n { n = $0 } END { print n }'`

Comment: i dont think the issue with sort | head. since i try to run ssh user@103.11.34.111 "find /data/path -name 'CDR*$file_date' or ssh user@103.11.34.111 "find /data/path  -printf '%TY-%Tm-%Td %TH:%TM:%.2TS\n' it manage to get expected result. however if i run with full parameter, it got error buffer overflow

Comment: How do you ensure that the variable `file_date` is defined on the remote side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `$file_date` is not visible on the remote server because you are using single quotes. The crucial change to fix that is to use double quotes.  You have to switch to single quotes internally (or otherwise escape or quote the other quotes).

```
ssh user@103.11.34.111 "find /data/path -name 'CDR*$file_date' -printf '%TY-%Tm-%Td %TH:%TM:%.2TS\n' | sort -rn | head -1"
```

See also [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)

The pipe to `sort | head` is rather memory-intensive; keeping all the lines in memory so that they can be sorted is superfluous when all you need is the overall maximum value. So the following should be both more efficient in terms of memory and run faster.

```
ssh user@103.11.34.111 "find /data/path -name 'CDR*$file_date' -printf '"%TY-%Tm-%Td %TH:%TM:%.2TS\n"' |
    awk '\$0 > n { n = $0 } END { print n }'"
```

Notice how the dollar sign in the Awk script needs to be backslash-escaped because the double quotes will cause anything with an unescaped dollar sign to be evaluated as a variable by the local shell before `ssh` runs.

If you don't expect a lot of output, you could run the `sort` and `head` locally, in which case no quoting is required around the pipeline.

```
ssh user@103.11.34.111 find /data/path -name "CDR*$file_date" -printf "'%TY-%Tm-%Td %TH:%TM:%.2TS\n'" |
sort -rn | head -1
```

... but as I expect the `find` command to potentially produce a nontrivial amount of output, I have assumed you want to run the entire pipeline remotely, and only send the final result back over the `ssh` connection.

I'll emphasize again that this only runs `ssh find` and then pipes the output back to your local shell, which runs the pipeline through `sort` and `head` locally.

(And even then, the Awk script from above is probably an improvement over keeping all the lines you receive in memory at the same time so you can sort them.)

Notice also how the argument to `-printf` needs to be doubly quoted (as in, both double and single quoted; or you could backslash-escape the space) to keep it as a single string from both the local and the remote shell.

Comment: Perhaps see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937792/using-variables-inside-a-bash-heredoc/54434993#54434993 which however discusses here documents, not quoted strings. The same lessons broadly apply.

Comment: using single quote in variable does not send the variable value when running command inside ssh. i suspect buffer overflow happens because there is variable that cant be read when we passing the command. that is why encapsulate variable with double quotes. The same issue happens  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314660/passing-variables-in-remote-ssh-command however this solution can solve if we have only one parameter that need encapsulate of double quote, not multiple.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to say. I think you can easily verify that `ssh user@103.11.34.111 "echo 'CDR*$file_date'"` does what you expect whereas `user@103.11.34.111 'echo "CDR*$file_date"'` does not.